# How to get data by Serialize method in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want get list data from server, below is my code:

```
//server side
var forms = db.forms.where(f => f.user_id == 12);
return View(forms.toList());

//client side, in javascript
@model IEnumerable<Workflow.Models.form>
<script>
  var formdata = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
</script>
```

but explorer always report error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Can someone please help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a WebForms construct (`<%= ... %>`) inside a Razor view.

Try using the following:

```
<script>
    var formdata = @Html.Raw(new JavascriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);
</script>
```